# Grails 2.0: Invalid SHA1

Tags: grails, ivy, sha, grails-2.0, buildconfig

Often I get and *invalid SHA1* error when executing *run-app* in Grails 2.0.0.RC1, especially with depedencies to our pwn products/modules.

I have found the following Jira case:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7313

Unfortunately the following line in *BuildConfig.groovy*

```
ivySettings.setVariable("ivy.checksums", "")
```

results in the error:

```
| Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.setVariable() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [ivy.checksums, ] (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Regards

Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ivySettings.setVariable("ivy.checksums", "")
```

should work if you put it inside the resolution closure e.g.

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ivySettings.setVariable("ivy.checksums", "")
}
```

but

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    checksums false
}
```

is the right way to do it for Grails 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 3):

[Bobby Warner's comment](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7313?focusedCommentId=65976&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-65976) suggests the new way to disable checksums is:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    checksums false
}
```